# How to display tables using dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I am trying to display two tables using dropdown box choices.

I'm using this JS code. Here's [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4K9hM/)

```
 function change_tbl(dhi)
           {
                      if(dhi=='')
                     {
                            return;
                     }
                     $('#tbl_div div').css('display','none');
                     $('#'+dhi).css('display','block');
          }
```

but it isn't working. How?
I need first table to display on load. (Means first table should be default choice.)
Any solutions?

Comment: please share the relevant html also

Comment: Check the console also, you've got "Uncaught ReferenceError: change_tbl is not defined" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the function in `onchange()` like

```
<select onchange="change_tbl(this.value)">
    <option value="">select table</option>
    <option value="tb1">table 1</option>
    <option value="tb2">table 2</option>
</select>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y6ahv/)

Also in the fiddle there are few other problems like

1. jQuery was not included
2. since `change_tbl` is used in an inline handler you need to declare it in the global scope - select No Wrap Head/Body in the second dropdown in the left panel

---

Use a jQuery event handler like

```
<select id="table-select">
    <option value="">select table</option>
    <option value="tb1" selected>table 1</option>
    <option value="tb2">table 2</option>
</select>
```

then use a [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler to register the change event handler

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#table-select').change(function () {
        $('#tbl_div > div').css('display', 'none');
        if (this.value) {
            $('#' + this.value).css('display', 'block');
        }
    }).change(); //this is used to trigger a manual change handler initially so that the state is properly set on page load
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qCjGf/)

Also read: [Document Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), [trigger handler](http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/), [change() handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/), [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: what if i need to display table 1 as default choice? i tried selected="selected"...it doesnt work.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. that's helpful. will you explain the jquery function, pls ?

Answer (score 0):

**Demo :**  http://jsfiddle.net/4K9hM/3/

**Html:**

```
<select id="tt" >
    <option value="">select table</option>
    <option value="tb1">table 1</option>
    <option value="tb2">table 2</option>
</select>
<div id="tbl_div">

    <div id="tb1">
        <table border="1">
            <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="tb2">
       <table border="1">
           <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
           <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tt").change( function ()
        {
            dhi = $("#tt").val();
             if(dhi=='')
            {
                return;
            }
            $('#tbl_div div').css('display','none');
            $('#'+dhi).css('display','block');
        });
});
```